# ViewPager data retention

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am new to using `ViewPagers` and `Fragments` in Android.  The initial activity of my app has a `ListView` which then goes to another activity which is basically a filtered `ListView` based on an id passed from the inital `ListView`.  I'd like the user to be able to swipe between the different filtered `ListViews`.  It's probably my general lack of understanding, but I have the `ViewPager` functionality working fine, but when I click on an item in the filtered `ListView` I'm getting an error thrown because I have a collection of values I'm storing as a member variable that I reference throughout the class and the collection is always empty when using the `ViewPager`.

This the code I have so far:

ListingFragment.class:

```
public class ListingFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;  
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter; 
    private static List<Fragment> fragments;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);  
        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);

        DetailsFragment df1 = DetailsFragment.newInstance(1);
        fragments.add(df1);

        DetailsFragment df2 = DetailsFragment.newInstance(2);
        fragments.add(df2);
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {  

            return fragments.get(index);
        }  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
             return 2;  
        }  
   }
}
```

DetailsFragment.class

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private int detailId;
    private static List<Integer> items;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onActivityCreated(icicle);
    }

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int id) {

        DetailsFragment lf = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        lf.setArguments(bundle);
        return lf;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listing, container, false);

        detailId = getArguments().getInt("id");         

        items = GetItems();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        final Integer item = items.get(pos); //this is always empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has its problems but it should work:

Check your names, you have `ListingFragment` which extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` which seems to be an `Activity`(if it is an `Activity` then you picked an awful name) and you also have `DetailsFragment` which extends the same `SherlockFragmentActivity` which seems to be a `Fragment`

Don't use a list of fragment for the `ViewPager`'s adapter, this will work initially but you'll get in trouble if you rotate the phone. You can use the list but you'll need to make certain modification to the adapter.

Don't make `items` `static`  because, as you use the same class `DetaildFragment` for both pages of the adapter,  the `items` list will always point to the last result returned by `GetItems()`.

Finally, regarding the `items` problem, can you share a stacktrace with the exception? Have you tested `GetItems` to see if it returns a valid list with all the data?

Comment: I think I've pinpointed the problem.  The wrong id is being passed in.  It seems when I scroll, instead the id that is being passed in, is one ahead of where it should be.  So, in my example, when I scroll to fragment that should pass in id 1, is 2 is being passed in.  Does anything in the `ListingFragment.class` above indicate what could cause that?

Comment: @KrisB No, I don't see something obvious(is that the real code you're using). Are you sure you aren't mistaken fragments in the `ViewPager` (`ViewPager` should first start at position 0(with the id 1) and have another fragment to swipe to with the id 2)?

Comment: Yea, I'm going to start a new question because I have additional code, but I don't want to keep adding to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You pass **int position** to onListItemClick() method but in get()method you use **pos**. Try to replace

```
final Integer item = items.get(pos);
```

with

```
final Integer item = items.get(position);
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo by me.  It's not the `pos` or the `position` variable that is the issues, its the collection being empty, though.